# how to submit a form after checking every input

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    $('#f_name, #l_name').change(function(){

        if($(this).val().length < 2)
        {
            $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
            alert('names must be at least 2 symbols');
            checked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).css('border', '1px solid lime');
            checked = true;
        }


    });
```

let say I've checked every input, like the above, but how Do I use this checkeds variables in the last click, when the user submits the form using the jquery submit()?

what if I have 10 inputs and checkboxes, radioboxes? that I need to check in the change handler

Comment: You could use the jQuery Validation Plugin for this: http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Comment: Life doesn't have to be this boring dude, try Abide http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/abide.html. Anyway it is HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about eventHandlers? Or give the submit button you chose a js function à la 'checkBefore()' where you submit the form after checking.

Comment: Can you give an example?